# Capture event - user copy, paste, cut

Tags: jquery, primefaces

I need to capture a user event when a user copies, pastes or cuts text into a text field and am using the following JQuery snippet but it doesn't appear to be capturing the event.

Any ideas ?

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('f:t:componentName')).bind({
         copy: function () {
             $('#message').text('copy behaviour detected!');
         },
         paste: function () {
             $('#message').text('paste behaviour detected!');
         },
         cut: function () {
             alert("cut");
             $('#message').text('cut behaviour detected!');
         }
     });
 });
```

Comment: Are you sure your selector is valid? What does `console.log($(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('f:t:componentName')).length)` show?

Comment: Selector is valid this shows '1'

Comment: Works here: http://plnkr.co/edit/cMpD87fHqJe7AUwfTHKz?p=preview. Must be related to your selector.